# How can I get the list of all wifi that are near me on my Application in Swift, with Third Party Library

Tags: swift, wifi

I am try to make an application which show all the near by wifi List on my application. The SSID of all the wifi on a tableview but there is very less information in it. If there is any third party library that can show this that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not. Apple did not provide list of near by wifi. But there is a way to get a list. 
Apple provide list in special case. You have to follow certain steps and give some answers of questions with Apple support. You have to prove that you application is based on Wi-Fi management like Xender

For now you can get only connected SSID and BSSID of your connected AP(Access Point). and You will get ssid and bssid of connected hotspot in below or equivalent iOS 10. 
for more info read [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1942/_index.html) and [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88418)

EDIT **SWIFT 3**

```
func printCurrentWifiInfo() {
  if let interface = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() {
    for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interface) {
      let interfaceName: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interface, i)
      let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, to: AnyObject.self)
      if let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)" as CFString), let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData as? [String : AnyObject] {
        // connected wifi
        print("BSSID: \(interfaceData["BSSID"]), SSID: \(interfaceData["SSID"]), SSIDDATA: \(interfaceData["SSIDDATA"])")
      } else {
        // not connected wifi
      }
    }
  }
}
```